# DynamoDB not as scalable as it seems?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

it is known that DynamoDB is highly scalable.
Let's take a look at 2 scenarios

> Scenario 1:  I create a DynamoDB table with on-demand mode
>
> Scenario 2:  I create a DynamoDB table with provisioned mode (1500
> RCUs and 500 WCUs)

Now let's say a super violent write traffic spike happens: 25 000 write operations in 1 second.

Regarding the scenario 1, when creating an on-demand table, there are only 4 partitions that are automatically created (or a number of partitions close to that value). Therefore even if the PutItem API call is using different partition keys (evenly distributed), the clients will get throttling errors. (DynamoDB will have to split partitions to cope with the load, this takes some time, hence the clients get throttling errors in the meantime).

Regarding scenario 2, there is only 1 partition, so all the PutItems will store data in that partition.
DynamoDB will not be able to cope with the load, even with the burst capacity, the hard limit of a partition is 1000 WCUs. I will have to increase the WCU of the table.

Therefore is it correct to say that:

> When creating a DynamoDB table using on-demand, if there is an extremely violent traffic spike
> (PutItem for instance), DynamoDB is not able to accept all the
> PutItem, DynamoDB will have to split partitions to get more WCUs. In the meantime DynamoDB will respond throttling errors

Also, how long does it takes for DynamoDB to split a partition ?
(just so I can get an idea how long a client has to wait with throttling errors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trust me, DynamoDB is as scalable as it seems. Let me help with your concerns:

### Scenario 1

You create an on-demand table, which you get 4 partitions to serve your data. Each partition is capable of handling 1000 WCU and 3000 RCU. So for a new on-demand table with evenly distributed writes, you will see throttling if you try to exceed 4000 WCU instantly. For this reason we have documented how to pre-warm your on-demand table to ensure it meets the scale you require out of the box.

##### Pre-warming

With on-demand capacity mode, the requests can burst up to double the previous peak on the table. Note that throttling can occur if the requests spikes to more than double the default capacity or the previously achieved peak request rate within 30 minutes. One solution is to pre-warm the tables to the anticipated peak capacity of the spike.

To pre-warm the table, follow these steps:

1. Make sure to check your account limits and confirm that you can reach the desired capacity in provisioned mode.
2. If you're pre-warming a table that already exists, or a new table in on-demand mode, start this process at least 24 hours before the anticipated peak. You can only switch between on-demand and provisioned mode once per 24 hours.
3. To pre-warm a table that's currently in on-demand mode, switch it to provisioned mode and wait 24 hours. Then go to the next step.
4. If you want to pre-warm a new table that's in provisioned mode, or has already been in provisioned mode for 24 hours, you can proceed to the next step without waiting.
5. Set the table's write throughput to the desired peak value, and keep it there for several minutes. You will incur cost from this high volume of throughput until you switch back to on-demand.
6. Switch to On-Demand capacity mode. This should sustain the provisioned throughput capacity values.

[src](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadWriteCapacityMode.html#HowItWorks.PreWarming)

### Scenario 2

You provision your table to have 500 WCU, but you expect it to be able to provide you more than 1 single partition? If you have a single partition you are correct that you can only burst to its hard limit, which is 1000 WCU.

If you scale beyond 1000 WCU, then DynamoDB will add new partitions which can sometimes take a couple of seconds/minutes. However, just like scenario 1, if you expect to reach a peak of 30,000 WCU, then pre-warm your table to that amount. Now when your autoscaling needs more than 1000 WCU, it can scale instantly.

---

**TLDR;** Pre-warm your DynamoDB table if you expect to scale, that way you can scale seamlessly from the beginning.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed answer. Crystal clear :-)

Comment: Excellent. Happy scaling =⁠_⁠=